# pandas applymap inside a function without a copy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df`, and define a function to be applied on the entire dataframe using `applymap`.

```
 def f(x):
    return x*2

 def master(df):
      return df.applymap(f)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
     df = pd.DataFrame(d.items())
     df_2 = master(df)
```

Is there a way to use `applymap` on `df` inside the `master` function without having to make a copy?

I´m thinking something on the lines of

```
 def f(x):
    return x*2

 def master(df):
      df.applymap(f)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
     df = pd.DataFrame(d.items())
     master(df)
```

and on main df would have been changed.

*EDIT*
the `f` function is more complicated that this one, of course, and I want to apply a sequence of functions to transform the data frame. There are basically string parsers to normalize, transform to unicode, remove characters, split into components, etc, so so far I can´t see a way to do it without `applymap`.

Comment: Can't you just `return df.applymap(f)` directly in `master`?

Comment: What do you mean with "without making a copy"? You are changing the values of the dataframe (it's `x * 2` that will make a copy)

Comment: I´m thinking on being able to change df without having to return it on master.

Comment: So you want to be able to do `master(df)` instead of `df = master(df)`? The `applymap` method has no `inplace` argument you can set, so I don't think there is an easy solution. But what is wrong with the explicit `df = master(df)`?

Comment: Yes. The dataframes that I´m going to work gonna be large, so less copies = less memory.

Comment: Note that this will not take less copies. Returning a dataframe does not take an extra copy, it is the modifying which copies the values, but that will happen anyway in your example.

Comment: It seems that applymap is doing a copy here, either on change or the return. On the first example, after applying `master`, df is not changed. If there was a way to change it without making a copy I believe that the memory culprit would be lower.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible that `applymap` is taking a copy, but you can only change this by *not* using applymap, this will not be solved with returning the dataframe from the function or not.

Comment: Can you give more insight in what you want to apply? (the simple example you give can of course easily be done without `applymap`, but maybe your real function as well?)

Answer (score 0):

You can global df. This way you can acces it anywhere and you can change it anywhere. Whoever. The function is pretty useless becaus of this. `global df`

Comment: Yeah, globals are not really an option.